# Refreshing a Table in a Partial View

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to make some blocks of code work from a blank MVC project (no authentication) before applying its logic to my actual project but I can't seem to do it right. I'm trying to have a table in a partial view to reload/refresh/update itself every certain span of time so it'll reflect any changes that was made and that happened in another webpage/browser.

The snippet that fires a function every few second work but the rendering/refreshing is where it gets trippy. I've been following this example with no luck ([Refresh Partial View Div in MVC 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082741/refresh-partial-view-div-in-mvc-5)).

Here are my code:
View(Index.cshtml)

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<div id="peopletablediv">
    @{ Html.RenderAction("Person");}
</div>
```

Partial View (Person.cshtml)
    @model IEnumerable

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Controller(PeopleController.cs)

```
public class PeopleController : Controller
{
    private WebApplication1Context db = new WebApplication1Context();

    // GET: People
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Person()
    {
        return PartialView(db.People.ToList());
    }
}
```

JavaScript(within the index.cshtml only since I'm just testing)

```
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var url = '@Url.Action("Person")';
        var div = $("#peopletablediv");
        setInterval(function () {
            div.load(url);
        }, 2000);
    });
</script>
```

I've only a few months experience in asp.net MVC and web development in general. Which part would I be getting wrong here?

Comment: what do you mean by `gets trippy`?

Comment: From what I observed in runtime, the table refreshes itself into how it rendered at first execution. Like if the table had 1 person, the table will refresh itself within 2 seconds into that even if there are more than 1 person in the database.

Comment: are you hitting a break point inside the `Person()` action every 2 seconds? if not you're probably caching the result and should add the `[OutputCache(Duration=0)]` attribute. if that throws an error since it's a child action set the Duration to 1 instead

Comment: Thank you JamieD77 that seem to have solved it! the code worked and my problem was apparently the caching.